# How to recreate .pb file with own dataset

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am using tensorflow and Inception v3.
How can I recreate the file (classify_image_graph_def.pb) used in [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) if I was training with my own dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run retrain.py on your own dataset it automatically creates output_graph.pb and output_labels.txt in /tmp directory (You can change this by passing --output_graph argument). So you need no to worry about this.